# Mongodb has a bug on "$lte" (query or aggregation) while searching for dates ranges

Tags: database, mongodb, date, mongodb-compass, non-relational-database

**Scenario**:

I have a db hosted on MongoDb Atlas.

This db has a collection which, among other data, has a `created` field of type `Date`.

```
pseudoCode Schema:
... {
created: { type: Date }
}...
```

I want to perform a query that allows me to find all the objects existing in the collection which have a `created` value between specifics days `including` the boundary dates.

Let's assume that the date range is `2020-08-01` and `2020-08-31`, the query would be

```
{created: {'$gte': new Date('2020-08-01'), '$lte': new Date('2020-08-31')}}
```

right?

**Wrong**.

By doing the query this way, I only get results that are `greater than or equal to` "2020-08-01" and `lower than` "2020-08-31". Meaning that, even if I'm performing an `$lte` query, I always get the `$lt` results.

**Tests I did**

I've tested this **only for a type Date field** atm on different collections and having consistently the same issue. Didn't have time for further investigations on different data types yet.

I've tested it on `aggregation $match` pipelines and `find` queries on:

- my codebase
- a clean script that just does this operations
- directly on MongoDb Compass

In all 3 cases, the results are consisent with the problem exposed and confirm the problem.

**Quick fix**

Simply use `$lt` instead of `$lte` and always consider 1 day more than you intended.
Using the previous example, the query will become

```
{created: {'$gte': new Date('2020-08-01'), '$lt': new Date('2020-09-01')}}
```

and in this case, I'm getting the expected date range "2020-08-01" - "2020-08-31" results.

**Note** that I could have also used `$lte` and I would get the exact same results however, the `$lt` form is logically more correct for whom is reading the code.

**Why I'm posting this**

I did find few people have posted about this issue across the years, more relevant links are [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2811) (initially the dev believed the problem was with mongoose, then a solution proposed to check the schema but that's not the issue since in my case the schema is properly defined and I've tested it on Compass directly) and this [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/mongodb-user/c/QsYE_3x0HFA?pli=1) (the problem is poorly stated and received no answer).

But I did not find a solution.

Even though I've quick fixed the issue, I wanted to point it out better and understand if:

- I'm doing something wrong and this is the expected behavior
- there is something I'm doing wrong in my query
- there is a problem with `$lte` which need to be addressed properly

Who has ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `new Date('2020-08-01')` then the result is actually `ISODate("2020-08-01T00:00:00Z")`

So

```
{created: {'$gte': new Date('2020-08-01'), '$lte': new Date('2020-08-31')}}
```

becomes

```
{created: {'$gte': ISODate("2020-08-01T00:00:00Z"), '$lte': ISODate("2020-08-31T00:00:00Z")}}
```

i.e. day 2020-08-31 is not included. You may also consider time zones if data was inserted as local time and thus not stored as `2020-08-02T00:00:00Z` but `2020-08-02T02:00:00Z` for example.

One solution is to add one day and use `$lt`:

```
{created: {'$gte': new Date('2020-08-01'), '$lt': new Date('2020-09-01')}}
```

or you can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) like this:

```
{created: {'$gte': new Date('2020-08-01'), '$lte': moment.utc('2020-08-31').endOf('day').toDate()}}
```

or perhaps `moment.utc('2020-08-01').endOf('month').toDate()`

Comment: that's something I didn't think of! I was focused on the date and I completely ignored to consider the hour part which is still passed after the conversion in the query. D'oh! I'm waiting a bit more to see if there are any other answers but I think we have a winner here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix**

Simply use `$lt` instead of `$lte` and always consider 1 day more than you intended.
Using the previous example, the query will become

```
{created: {'$gte': new Date('2020-08-01'), '$lt': new Date('2020-09-01')}}
```

and in this case, I'm getting the expected date range "2020-08-01" - "2020-08-31" results.

**Note** that I could have also used `$lte` and I would get the exact same results however, the `$lt` form is logically more correct for whom is reading the code.